# std::vector etc unnecessarily (erroneously?) instantiates nested template argument type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

The following code compiles fine, even tough `std::plus<void>` would be illegal (in C++11).

```c++
template < typename > struct data {};
data<std::plus<void>> x; // does not attempt to complete std::plus<void>
```

which makes sense because `data<std::plus<void>>` does not need to instantiate `std::plus<void>`. However, it fails to compile when constructing a `std::vector`, which somehow causes instantiation of `std::plus<void>`.

```c++
std::vector<data<std::plus<void>>> v;
```

The error is:

```c++
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.5/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:496:29: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
_Tp operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.5/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2055:27: note: in instantiation of
template class 'std::__1::plus<void>' requested here
decltype(__is_constructible_test(declval<_Tp>(), declval<_Args>()...))
```

A similar error on g++4.8 or with `std::list`.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I'm... curious why this matters. What real program could encounter this?

Comment: I tried to use `std::plus<void>` as a tag.

Answer (score 3):

> The following code compiles fine, even tough `std::plus<void>` would be
>   illegal (in C++11).

Since C++1y the standard garantees the following explicit specialization to be made:

```
template <> struct plus<void> {
    template <class T, class U> constexpr auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const
    -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u));

    typedef unspecified is_transparent;
};
```

---

The problem for actually incomplete template arguments (like `void` for `std::plus` in C++11) is:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when
>   instantiating a template component, **unless specifically allowed for
>   that component.**

The reason why your programm encounters undefined behavior is that `std::plus` is instantiated with `void` which is an incomplete type.

The reason why writing

```
std::plus<void> p;
```

does **not** cause a compiler error (whilst causing UB) is that the member function of a template is **not instantiated until used**.

Comment: If instead of `std::plus<void>` I had used a declared-only `struct plus;` without defining it, `std::vector<data<plus>>` would compile just fine. Should I never write code like this since its effect is still undefined according your quote of the standard?

Comment: The standard quote applies for a **standard library component**, instantiating an own template like `data` with an incomplete type (here `plus`) is absolutely fine. Only instantiating a standard library template with an incomplete type, for which it is not explicitly allowed, is undefined bevaior.